# Oracle TO_DATE function parallel in Mysql which should support both DB oracle and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate, createquery

Initially, I was facing one weird problem, below query was running fine in Oracle SQL developer.

```
select * from sbill.act_sub_t where (act_sub_t.unsub_dt - act_sub_t.sub_dt) < 100;
```

but I was facing below issue in java `Parameter value [100] did not match expected type[java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)]`

Below was the java code,

```java
Query query1 = entityManager.createQuery("select * from ActSubT where (ActSubT.unsub_dt - ActSubT.sub_dt)<:days").setParameter("days", 100);
```

So to fix that problem I had used `TO_DATE` function in my java query and I was able to run in java

```
select * from sbill.act_sub_t where (TO_DATE(ActSubT.unSubDt, 'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE(ActSubT.actualUnsubDt, 'DD-MM-YYYY')) < 100;
```

But actual problem is that my application supports both Oracle and MySQL Db and that `TO_DATE` function does not support in MYSQL so this query will not run when this application will run on MySQL.

So do we have any common parallel function of `TO_DATE` which supports both Oracle and MySQL?

Comment: `CAST(ActSubT.unSubDt AS DATE)`should work for both databases...

Comment: What is the datatype of the columns?

Comment: @Radagast81  i just tried that solution this is my query  select ActSubT.id,ActSubT.actId from ActSubT ActSubT where (CAST(ActSubT.unsubDt AS DATE) - CAST(ActSubT.subDt AS DATE) ) < 10  

but now i am getting below exception 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Could not resolve requested type for CAST : DATE [select ActSubT.id,ActSubT.actId from com.sbill.app.domain.ActSubT ActSubT where (CAST(ActSubT.unsubDt AS DATE) - CAST(ActSubT.subDt AS DATE) ) < 10]

Comment: @SalmanA   Java side my data type name is LocalDateTime  and in oracle data type is DATE

Comment: Hmm, that is a problem of hibernate, does `cast(act_sub_t.unsub_dt - act_sub_t.sub_dt as int)` work?

Comment: @Radagast81   Thanks for your support :)
In my old query i changed 'Date' capital to small case 'date' then it works .
and this new solution also works.
thanks again.

Comment: @Radagast81     As of now i did't test it with mysql hope it will work , i will test it.

Comment: Posted my suggestions as answer, so you can accept it, if it works for mysql as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like hibernate doesn't check that `act_sub_t.unsub_dt` and `act_sub_t.sub_dt` are of type `DATE`.

As `TO_DATE` is Oracle only, you can use the `CAST`-function which is common in your databases:

```
CAST(ActSubT.unsubDt AS date) - CAST(ActSubT.subDt AS date)
```

or

```
CAST(ActSubT.unsubDt - ActSubT.subDt AS int)
```

should be a good substitute.

Comment: I have one more query it would be good if you can help on that..
select TO_DATE(e.created_dt, 'dd-mm-yy'),sum(CURRENT_BAL) from sbill.act_resource_t e group by TO_DATE(e.created_dt, 'dd-mm-yy');

here i have used TO_DATE because i wanted to group by just on date without time.   

here what can i use which can run on both oracle and mysql  ?

Comment: I doubt that there is a solution that works for both databases Oracle `TRUNC(e.created_dt)` vs. MySQL `DATE(e.created_dt)`...

Comment: whenever i need to calculate diff b/w two date i do date2 - date1 so will it work with mysql too ?

Comment: It should, i don't have the settings to test it. But as you tested it once, i'm sure it will work in all cases.